# How to read xml file into vb/C#.net to show in grid using data table?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i want to read this quiz.xml file in C#.NET to show in grid using data table.
n later on i want to insert this data into my actual sql server database.

m not getting how to do this...so can anyone please  help me....thanks in advance...
thanx in adv.

**quiz.xml** :
[click here to download](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?cmlpybalcmcrmpa)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="quiz.xsd">
    <mchoice>
    <question>What is the capital city of Australia?</question>
        <answer>Sydney</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Canberra</answer>
    <answer>Melbourne</answer>
    <answer>Gold Coast</answer>
</mchoice>
    <mchoice>
    <question>Launceston is the second largest city in which Australian state?</question>
    <answer>Victoria</answer>
    <answer>New South Wales</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Tasmania</answer>
    <answer>Western Australia</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>Which state has the famous 'Twelve Apostles' ?</question>
    <answer correct="yes">Victoria</answer>
    <answer>South Australia</answer>
    <answer>New South Wales</answer>
    <answer>Western Australia</answer>
</mchoice>
    <mchoice>
    <question>Which is a popular ski resort in NSW?</question>
    <answer correct="yes">Perisher Blue</answer>
    <answer>Mt. Buller</answer>
    <answer>Mt. Baw-Baw</answer>
    <answer>Lake Mountain</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>Which of the following is NOT Australian native animals?</question>
    <answer>Kangaroo</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Penguin</answer>
    <answer>Koala</answer>
    <answer>Wombat</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>Which city has an extensive tram network?</question>
    <answer>Sydney</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Melbourne</answer>
    <answer>Adelaide</answer>
    <answer>Ballarat</answer>
</mchoice>
    <mchoice>
    <question>What is known as 'The Silver City' in Australia?</question>
    <answer>Alice Springs</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Broken Hill</answer>
    <answer>Ballarat</answer>
    <answer>Silverton</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>In which location the war movie 'Thin Red Line' was taken?</question>
    <answer>Anglesea</answer>
    <answer>Apollo Bay</answer>
    <answer>Margaret River</answer>
    <answer>Monkey Mia</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Townsville</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>Which is NOT true about Uluru ?</question>
    <answer>It is the world biggest monolith located in the centre of Australian continent</answer>
    <answer>It was named 'Ayers Rock' by European explorer William Gosse in 1873</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">Aboriginal people encourage tourists to climb Uluru</answer>
    <answer>The area contains carvings and paintings by Aboriginal people</answer>
</mchoice>
<mchoice>
    <question>What is so special about Longreach?</question>
    <answer>The place where a blacksmith named Thomas Hiscock found the first gold that triggerred gold rush</answer>
    <answer>The town has an expansive, well-preserved penal colony of Australia's early history</answer>
    <answer correct="yes">The first commercial flight by Qantas took from this town in 1921</answer>
    <answer>None of these answers are correct</answer>
</mchoice>
</quiz>
```

Comment: `m nt getting how to do this..so cn ne 1 plz help me.. thanx in adv.` Has problem with your keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `"ReadXml"` method of the `"System.Data.DataTable"` class and pass the xml data (or even the file path!) through it, then bind the grid view to the table by setting the `"DataSource"` property.

Hope it helps.

Cheers